# Is it possible to view summaries of class methods which are instantiated using interface?

Tags: c#, class, interface, summary

I have an interface which is implemented by lots of classes. I have set summaries for methods in these classes and also in the interface. The problem is I am instantiating class objects as follows:

```
MyInterface object = new MyClass();
```

This is a design rule so I have to instantiate class objects using the interface. However, I have more in-depth summaries set in class methods for the developers. Is it possible to make the developer who will use these interface and classes view the summaries set in class instead of the ones in interface? My concern is with C#. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "summary" here?

Comment: What I mean is XML comments that pop up during development. Such as when you call a method(write it), a notification box pops up that describes the method you have written.  You can check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc

Comment: "This is a design rule so I have to instantiate class objects using the interface." Given that you apparently want the programmer to be interacting with the specific implementation, rather than the generic interface, your design rule is at odds with your actual requirements.  You should use interfaces when you actually need the functionality they give you, not in every situation, even when it's opposed to the actual needs of your program.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: **no, this is not currently possible out-of-the-box with VS**.

Consider your example.  `MyInterface object = new MyClass();`

At design time, `object` has a type of `MyInterface`, not `MyClass`.  One could make the argument that the IDE could do a tiny bit more analysis to figure out the type is `MyClass`.

Now consider this code:

```
MyInterface object = new MyClass();
if (some_runtime_variable == false) { object = new MyClassToo(); }
```

Now what should the tooltip read?  The IDE has no way to know what the value of `some_runtime_variable` is going to be.  And nothing prevents hundreds of classes from implementing `MyInterface`, so an argument of "show all the docs" isn't going to fly.

You could, theoretically, write a VS add-on that would accomplish your goals, but you would need to address the issue I've outlined above.